# How should I make a game master using firestore and firebase cloud functions?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, countdowntimer

I am making a web game. When certain time is reached, a new round should begin. Therefore, a firestore document should be changed at the time. I implemented this by calling a cloud function locally, counting timer on the client with the local time. However if the client closes the connection, the cloud function cannot be launched. How could I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that google cloud scheduler functions has evolved to cloud tasks. I think this would perfectly match my circumstances. Having a look at the documentation.